# Yesterday sql call

Tags: php, mysql

The yesterday sql call that I have returns todays values and yesterdays values adding them together. I want to be able to SELECT only yesterdays values. Here is the code:

```
     tracking.timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The interval is set to NOW and 1 DAY. I want to be able to SELECT only yesterday. How can I SELECT only yesterday?

Comment: As far as I know, that query will select everything that is younger than 24 hours old, rather than everything that happened starting from midnight yesterday up until midnight today. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to SELECT from early morning yesterday until late night yesterday only basically all day yesterday

Comment: I was looking at this DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) it seems to do the same thing as NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `traking.timestamp` is stored as a unix timestamp, the following should do:

```
tracking.timestamp >= unix_timestamp(date_sub( current_date, interval 1 day ))
```

))

Comment: I was looking at this DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) it seems to do the same thing as NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

Comment: You could use `unix_timestamp` to convert it to a unix timestamp.

Or something in the above could help:

`select date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval 1 day) as yesterday, '2013-12-13 18:15:30' as timestamp, date_sub(concat(curdate(), ' 00:00:00'), interval 1 second) as today_minus_one;`

Comment: Check if the following gist helps you: https://gist.github.com/jfrioux/d5ff40d7798ed7f197d6